# How to calculate a new column based on the difference of different rows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate a column based on the difference of different rows within a dataframe. This would be something that would be simple to do in an Excel workbook, but I am trying to implement it in Python.

I usually calculate new columns with the standard df['c'] = df['a'] - df['b'], but I can only figure out how to use this form based on single row calculations, not ones that use two or more rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [6,3], [9,3]) #initial data frame
df['3'] = df[0]-df[1] #does not give me what I need

#looking for the end result to equal

df_good = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,0],[6,3,-2],[9,3,3])
```

Basically, for row x I want the new column to be the difference of the value in column 0 on row x-1 and the value in column 1 on row x.

Comment: `df['0'].shift() - df['1']`?

Comment: What is your logic?

Comment: @QuangHoang that won't work. It would have `NaN` for first row. Unless OP wants to `fillna(0)`.

Comment: @harvpan `shift(fill_value=0)` or `fillna(0)` afterwards.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much.

Comment: @QuangHoang, yep, that gives the output but we still do not know OP's logic. Unfortunately OP has only 2 rows and it is hard to predict the logic/pattern.